Markdown support in VsCode IntelliSense/Smart suggest
TLDR;
Is there a way to enable Markdown in VsCode IntelliSense/Smart suggest window?
Long story:
I started using Haskell and documentation often provides some extra info in markdown form, unfortunately VsCode seems not to support it and renders "cannot render inline math formula " text instead. Is there any way to enable it?
Example in Haskell docs

How it looks in VsCode

What VsCode trys to render


I've found it's a reported bug, so probably no solution yet https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/201
